# Name Search program problem. Getting an "reached end of file while parsing } error message

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I cant seem to get this code to compile, can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?
I have tried adding } all over the place but nothing seems to be working. Thank you so much!
What are some fixes I can use to get this code to compile correctly?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class NameSearch {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<String> searchName = new ArrayList <String>();
        String searchName = getNames();
        String boysNames;
        String girlsNames;

        displaySearchResults(searchName, boysNames, girlsNames);
    } 


    public static String getNames() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        File boysNames = new File("BoysNames.txt");
        Scanner inputFileBoysNames = new Scanner (boysNames);

        File girlsNames = new File("GirlsNames.txt");
        Scanner inputFileGirlsNames = new Scanner (girlsNames);

        System.out.println("Top 200 Name Search");
        System.out.print("Enter the name of your choosing here: ");

        String name = Keyboard.nextLine();
        Keyboard.close();
        return name;
    }

    public static void displaySearchResultsPing 
(String searchName, List<String> boysNames, List<String> girlsNames); 

    {

        System.out.println("\nBOOM! here are the results of your search: \n");

        boolean popularBoyName = boysNames.stream().anyMatch (p ->  p.equalsIgnoreCase(searchName));
        boolean popularGirlName = girlsNames.stream().anyMatch (p -> p.equalsIgnoreCase(searchName));


        if (popularBoyName) {
            System.out.println(searchName + "is a super popular boy's name. Pick another.");
        }
        if (popularGirlName) {
            System.out.println(searchName + "is a super popular girl's name. Pick another.");
        }
        if (!popularBoyName && !popularGirlName) {
            System.out.println (searchName + "is not a popular name. You have chosen correctly!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use an IDE.  Let it auto-format your code.  It'll use proper indentation so your code is readable, and will mark places where your syntax is incorrect.

Comment: The compilation errors generally point you to the right place to fix the error. Include the errors in your question so we can see what they are.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your `displaySearchResultsPing` method signature ends with a `;`.

Another is that in the `main` method you are calling `displaySearchResults()` but it doesn't exist.

Then you are reading names from files, but then discarding those variables. Eg:

```
File boysNames = new File("BoysNames.txt");  // this is never kept or returned
```

And the `boysNames` and `girlsNames` variables in the `main` method are never set to any value - always `null`.